# Is binomial test enough for metagenomic data?

Tags: binomial-distribution, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I'm having reads from metagenomic data from soil samples. I have 2 soil types, with 5 samples for each type. I have reads that I found out that are fungal, I have reads that are not fungal (but I haven't looked into what they are and it would be a hassle to do this) and I have reads that are unknown (no hits from the databases.

I wanted to see if there is any significant difference in regards to fungi abundance, in one type of the soil versus the other.

Being something even less than beginner in statistics here is an example for what I did: There are 10 fungal reads and 90 non fungal reads in sample 1. Lets say that samples 2, 3, 4, and 5 are identical to sample 1. Then lets say that there are 15 fungal reads and 85 non fungal reads in sample 6, while 7 ,8, 9 and 10 are identical to sample 6. Samples 1 - 5 are from soil type 1, samples 6 - 10 are from soil type 2. I sum the fungal reads from soil type 1 so I have 50 fungal reads and then I have 450 non fungal reads. I do the same for the samples of soil type 2: I have 75 fungal reads and 425 non fungal ones. I then perform a binomial test on these.

Does this approach make any sense? Do I need to look somewhere further?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly

> ... pulled all samples of the same type together ...`

is about. This is vague. You may want to give us a **precise** definition on what you are doing. A toy example is welcome, you could also write some equations to explain your idea. We shouldn't guess your intention.

Therefore, I can't really comment on your approach (because it's not clear to me). Let's take a took at the literature. STAMP (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2661018/) is a popular metagenomics statistical software.

- Calculate signficance between two treatments (that's **exactly** what you're looking for)
- It does that by pooling the replicates and form a t-test statistic
- It works on count data, and normalize it to proportion

I think the t-test framework may help you.

Comment: An example for what I mean: There are 10 fungal reads and 90 non fungal reads in sample 1. Lets say that samples 2, 3, 4, and 5 are identical to sample 1. Then lets say that there are 15 fungal reads and 85 non fungal reads in sample 6, while 7 ,8, 9 and 10 are identical to sample 6. Samples 1 - 5 are from soil type 1, samples 6 - 10 are from soil type 2. I sum the fungal reads from soil type 1 so I have 50 fungal reads and then I have 450 non fungal reads. I do the same for the samples of soil type 2: I have 75 fungal reads and 425 non fungal ones. I then perform a binomial test on these.

Comment: @Earendil Please edit to your question, so myself and others can study. When you edit, your question will bump to the first page.

Comment: I thought that using the t-test is not what I want since these are count data. Then I thought of using the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney rank sum test but then you loose the information of how many are non fungal reads (this is the case for the t test too). Then I thought of the binomial test, however with this the information of multiple samples per treatment is lost. However I am taking a look at the STAMP software which looks promising. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Earendil The paper uses t-test on normalized data. The normalized values are not count anymore. STAMP is popular, and I'm using it myself. The paper has been reviewed, so it's definitely a possibility.